# how to remove the initial slash from bundle file path, publicPath, PUBLIC_URL in webpack with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, create-react-app

How can we remove the initial slash from all the files included automatically in `index.html` from webpack (like `<script src="/static/js/...">`...) and all the paths of a react app?

How is possible to customize the `webpack.config.js` in a react project created by the command line `npx create-react-app` without ejecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

open the `public/index.html` removing all the slashes after/before `%PUBLIC_URL%`

for example

```html
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

become

```html
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%favicon.ico" />
```

---

2. 

if you use the variable `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in your jsx, remove always the slash after/before the variable.

for example

```js
const json = await http({ url: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/config.json`});
```

become

```js
const json = await http({ url: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}config.json`});
```

Create a empty file in the root of the project called `.env` entering this text:

```
PUBLIC_URL=
```

---

3. 

to replace the `publicPath` value of the `webpack.config.js` (you normally find this file in `/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`) without touching the original (**it is not recommended!!**) you can use a library like `react-app-rewired` or `craco`.

Below you can see an example with craco https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco :

After the installation by `npm i @craco/craco`

you need to replace some lines of your `package.json`

from

```js
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-script start",
    "build": "react-script build",
    "test": "react-script test",
    "eject": "react-script eject"
  },
...
```

to

```js
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
...
```

after that, in your root project add a file called `craco.config.js`

inside the file add the following code

```js
module.exports = {
    configure: {
      output: {
        publicPath: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that's it

Answer (score 2):

Part 1 of [Fancesco Orsi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71329216/10871073) fixed part of my problem, but the `/static/` appears to require messing with configs or adding libraries.

It was simpler to botch together a postscript that runs between my react and electron build. I'm sure people could repurpose this for what they need.

I made a JavaScript file with the following code and pointed a post-script in `package.json` to it.

`"postbuild": "node mid-build.js"`

```
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs');
let txt = readFileSync('./build/index.html');
txt = txt.toString().replaceAll('/static/', 'static/');
writeFileSync('./build/index.html', txt);
console.log('\nmid-build edits complete\n');
```

Not elegant, but it works and I can get back to debugging builds.

Comment: this will fail for images or other assets linked from the public folder

Comment: @Huzaifa Those can be manually fixed prior to building like part 1 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71329216/10871073)